# FXML file won't load even when file path is correct

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to load an FXML file:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/frontEnd/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml");

try {
    this.value = FXMLLoader.load(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I run, I get:

```
NullPointerException: Location is required
```

the path to my fxml file is:

```
src/frontEnd/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml
```

and the path to my class file is:

```
src/frontEnd/ModeScreen.java
```

`this.value extends AnchorPane` and the FXML file's root is an AnchorPane.

I checked and made sure that all of these files are in the bin folder and it doesn't run in either a jar file or Eclipse

I have also tried to use the following paths:

```
frontEnd/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml
../frontEnd/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml
src/frontEnd/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml
/src/frontEnd/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml
/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml
fxml/ModeScreen.fxml
```

I have also tried using `getResourceAsStream.toString`

file structure is as follows:

```
bin

    application

        Main

    frontEnd

        controllers

        fxml<---<all the fxml files are in here. I checked too.>

        ModeScreen.class
```

There must be some tiny thing I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your bin folder?

Comment: Just post it as text. Two other things might be helpful: the full stack trace, and also add a `System.out.println(url);` and show the result.

Comment: Edit the question to include the full stack trace. I suspect this has nothing at all to do with the path, and that there is some other error with your FXML.

Comment: It won't let me paste

Comment: and the url prints as null

Comment: and I wrote the wrong error down. I get NullPointerException. I changed it in the question

Comment: OK, so that definitely means it can't find the FXML file. I assume you have the file name correct (including case sensitivity) etc. The paths look right, it seems a bit odd. I would clean and rebuild the project in eclipse; after that I am a bit stumped.

Comment: rebuild did not fix it. but thank you anyways lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in here is that you are appending a `/`, when you are already using a [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)'s [`getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

You should never use a `/` at the beginning of a ClassLoader path is because all `ClassLoader paths are absolute`.

You can definitely use [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)'s [`getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) with a URL which starts with `/`, because before it delegates down to the classloader, it creates an absolute URL.

From the JavaDocs :

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.

The following are valid url :

Using ClassLoader :

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("frontEnd/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml");
```

Using Class :

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/frontEnd/fxml/ModeScreen.fxml");
```

Comment: Oh my goodness... I swear I tried that all ready lol. that worked. thank you very much.